# what new features come with a multidimensional database with SSAS 2017?

Tags: ssas

I cant find anything on what new features come out with SSAS 2017 for a multidimensional database. the only thing i can find is updates with the Tabular.
any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSAS 2017 is primarily focused on [new tabular features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/what-s-new-in-sql-server-analysis-services-2017?view=sql-server-2017). There is a new compatibility level for tabular ([1400](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/compatibility-level-for-tabular-models-in-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017)) but no new compatibility level for multidimensional.

There are several [discontinued and deprecated features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/analysis-services-backward-compatibility-sql2017?view=sql-server-2017), mainly for the multidimensional mode, and the default mode when installing is tabular now.